# How Scroll to Component Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, templates, vue-cli

I am working on a Single-Page-Website using the Vue-Cli and i have a Navigation with some Links in.

I have registered All my Components from the links in the Navigation-Component and i want to Scroll to the component when the link is clicked.

I tried to use the scrollIntoView() method but it didn't work. Can someone help me please?

here is my template:

```
<div class="right-nav">
  <div><a href="#" @click="scrollToComponent(el)">Infrastrukturen</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" >Gartenbau</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" >Karriere</a></div>
  <div><a href="#" >Kontakt</a></div>
  <div><a href="#">Impressum</a></div>
</div>
```

and here is my script:

```
<script>
import Kontakt from './kontakt.vue'
import Karriere from './karriere.vue'
import Gartenbau from './gartenbau.vue'
import Breitband from './breitband.vue'
import About from './about.vue'

export default {
  name: 'Navigation',
  components: {
      Kontakt,
      Karriere,
      Gartenbau,
      Breitband,
      About,

  },
    data:() => {
        return {
            defaultComp: 'About'
    }
  },
  methods:{
      scrollToComponent(el){
        const comp = el;
        if(comp){
            comp.scrollIntoView({
                behavior:"smooth"
            })
        }
    }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you should try this with https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-scrollto

Comment: Did you try to use $refs instead?

Comment: this worked thank you very much, i did some other mistakes that did not allow me to access the element.